# How to stop iOS keyboard interfering with UITextField position

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keyboard

I have a problem where the keyboard dismissal, I think interferes with the animation code I have. What I would like to happen is if the user clicks the search button while the keyboard is up, the keyboard drops and the text field will animate to the top of the screen. 
Like in this image.

http://imgur.com/5dQ6aPZ

However, what actually happens if the search button is pressed while the keyboard is up, is this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5dPS.jpg

Here is the code for the **Search button:**

```
- (IBAction)searchButton:(id)sender {

    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [UIView transitionWithView:_enterRoomLabel
                        duration:0.4
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                        animations:NULL
                        completion:NULL];

    _enterRoomLabel.hidden = YES;
    [_srcButton setHidden:YES];
    [_srcAgainButton setHidden:NO];


    [UITextField beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UITextField setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UITextField setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UITextField setAnimationDuration:0.3];

    _roomCodeInput.frame = CGRectMake(_roomCodeInput.frame.origin.x - 0.0, (_roomCodeInput.frame.origin.y - 105.0), _roomCodeInput.frame.size.width + 0.0, _roomCodeInput.frame.size.height);
    [UITextField commitAnimations];


}
```

**Search Again button**

```
- (IBAction)searchAgainButton:(id)sender {

[self.view endEditing:YES];
[UIView transitionWithView:_enterRoomLabel
                  duration:0.6
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:NULL
                completion:NULL];

_enterRoomLabel.hidden = NO;
[_srcButton setHidden:NO];
[_srcAgainButton setHidden:YES];


[UITextField beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UITextField setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UITextField setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UITextField setAnimationDuration:0.3];

_roomCodeInput.frame = CGRectMake(_roomCodeInput.frame.origin.x + 0.0, (_roomCodeInput.frame.origin.y + 105.0), _roomCodeInput.frame.size.width - 0.0, _roomCodeInput.frame.size.height + 0.0);
[UITextField commitAnimations];
}
```

And here are the methods I'm using **to dismiss the keyboard**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
[_roomCodeInput resignFirstResponder];
return NO;
}

-(void)dismissKeyboard{
[_roomCodeInput resignFirstResponder];
}
```

I'm just trying to find the best solution to solve this problem or perhaps re-design to something similar.
**Any Help would be greatly appreciated! :)**

Comment: have you tried to do this with autolayout constraints?  you can get notified when the keyboard frame changes so as to adjust the constraints to shift the elements around as needed.

Comment: @myte I think I seen that recently, I thought about it but I wasn't quite sure on how to actually implement that, ill have to look around more on that topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code as follows: 
Hope it will work now

**Search button:**

```
- (IBAction)searchButton:(id)sender {

    //[UITextField commitAnimations];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        _enterRoomLabel.hidden = YES;
        [_srcButton setHidden:YES];
        [_srcAgainButton setHidden:NO];

        _roomCodeInput.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, -100.0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // when animation
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        }];
    }];



}
```

**Search Again button**

```
- (IBAction)searchAgainButton:(id)sender {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        _enterRoomLabel.hidden = NO;
        [_srcAgainButton setHidden:YES];
        _roomCodeInput.text=Nil;

        _roomCodeInput.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // when animation
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            [_srcButton setHidden:NO];

        }];
    }];
```

Comment: You're a god !!
Thank you so much, I had posted a solution there where I just removed the search button during keyboard editing, but this does exactly what I want! 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray * vertConstraint;
UIButton * button;
UITextField * textField;

-(void)search{

    [self.view removeConstraints:vertConstraint];

    NSDictionary * viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button, textField);

    NSArray * newVertConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[textField(==30)]-(>=10)-[button]-10-|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary];

    [self.view addConstraints:newVertConstraint];

    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];

    vertConstraint = newVertConstraint;

}

self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(search) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Search" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[self.view addSubview:button];

textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
textField.layer.borderWidth = 5;
textField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
[self.view addSubview:textField];

[textField setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];
[button setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];

NSDictionary * viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button, textField);

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-20-[textField]-20-|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-20-[button]-20-|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];

vertConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-100-[textField(==30)]-10-[button]" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary];

[self.view addConstraints:vertConstraint];

[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Hey man thank you so much for your help, that seemed a bit messy to implement, but your idea did help me discover an easier solution!
I will post it as the solution for others to see.
Thanks very much for taking the time to help!! Very much appreciated